# Access code to split ranges

Tags: vba, ms-access

Currently I am making an access DB and one of the problems I'm getting is:

In `Table A` the field is a 6 digit number (123456). However the only way to relate `Table A` to `Table B` is the the same field in `Table B`.

The problem is for their data in `Table A` it is 6 digit integer but in `Table B` it is String.

Sometimes the people are lazy and instead of 3 rows titled 123456,123457,123458. They write 123456-458.

I want to use VBA to delete this row and replace it with 3 rows. How can I do this?

Comment: Fix the real problem not the symptoms. Data validation rules. Don't let users enter data this way.

Answer (score 1):

I am actually going to post this as an answer.

Access databases have the wonderful facility for data validation. You can restrict what a user inputs into the table in the first place rather than trying to handle the mess with complex code afterwards.

A  short [summary](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/restrict-data-input-by-using-validation-rules-b91c6b15-bcd3-42c1-90bf-e3a0272e988d):

You can vet or validate data in Access desktop databases as you enter it by using validation rules. You can use the expression builder to help you format the rule correctly. Validation rules can be set in either table design or table datasheet view. There are three types of validation rules in Access:

1. Field Validation Rule:   You can use a field validation rule to specify a criterion that all valid field values must meet.
2. Record Validation Rule:   You can use a record validation rule to specify a condition that all valid records must satisfy.
3. Validation on a form:   You can use the Validation Rule property of a control on a form to specify a criterion that all values input to that control must meet.

This means you can put restrictions on datatype, length.... all sorts.

Take some time to explore some of the tutorials available for setting up Access Databases. The greatest effort with databases should be the design not the maintenance.

See this excellent quick reference:

http://allenbrowne.com/ValidationRule.html

In case that link dies here are two quick excerpts:

Field validation:

[image: Field validation]

Table/Record validation:

[image: Table rules]

Comment: Thanks for the great answers. Here is the problem I have. This is a side project for my client I do not have access to these DB or rules. All I am doing is building a separate access DB for them. They give me a data dump from there main DB to a spreadsheet. So my job is to setup an easy way for them to use the data dump and insert it into my DB. Is the validation rules still the optimal solution. What happens if rows in the spreadsheet don't follow the rules?

Comment: Is this a one off dump where later your database will replace theirs?

Comment: So I'm designing 2 tables around 2 or 3 separate data dump spreadsheets. Every month they will have a new data dump to add to my table. This is something on the side to make a specific calculation/ overview. The names of the fields and the format of their data dumps will never change. I have to set up functions for them to import there data dumps and add it to my tables as easily as possible. The only problem I've ran into is separating ranges such as the one i listed above.